# Error parsing query: Unexpected character \"'\"" Graph QL

Tags: json, graphql, postman

I'm fairly new to GraphQL and I've been trying to call our graphQL server using postman with json format.

```
{"query":"query{stateQuery{avatar(address:'21638103') {action}}}"}
```

It always returns  Unexpected character "'"" but when I try to use my GraphQL query below. It would query successfully.

```
query {
  stateQuery {
    avatar(address: "21638103") {
      action
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Unexpected character "'"` means just what it says. It did not expect a `'`. Your example query that works uses `"21638103"` where the one that fails uses `'21638103'`. You need to use `"` instead of `'` for strings.

Answer (score 0):

GraphQL uses JSON ... [JSON specs](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) claims ...

> A string is a sequence of zero or more Unicode characters, wrapped in **double quotes**, using backslash escapes.

Comment: Hi, I've tried using 

{"query":"query{stateQuery{avatar(address: \\\"21638103\\\") {action}}}"} but the error still shows Unexpected character \"\\\""

Comment: use playground ... use some online json validator ... and strings wrappaed into double quotes .... and use variables for params https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#variables

Comment: It should most likely be `\"` instead of `\\\"`.